# Why is the python "dtype=float" 8-byte rather than 4-byte?

Tags: python, numpy, binary, floating-point

These days, I've switched from Matlab to NumPy/SciPy.

Today, I encountered a weird problem when I tried to load data stored in "binary format". Audio data is stored in the **4-byte single-precision floating point number**  format. I tried the following first.

```
data = np.fromfile('out.raw', dtype=float) # This is wrong
plt.plot(data)
```

But it didn't work. After some search, I tried the following, and it worked as expected:

```
data = np.fromfile('out.raw', dtype=np.float32) # This is okay.
plt.plot(data)
```

Based on my previous experience with C/C++, I had expected "float" to be a 4-byte single-precision floating point type. But it turns out that the float is 8-byte data, and in the above case, I should have used np.float32.

I have two questions regarding this.

**Q1**. **Why is the float 8-byte rather than 4-byte, which might be confusing to C/C++ programmers?**

**Q2**. **Why can't I use dtype=float32. This causes an error to me. I seems like I should use dtype=np.float32?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `float` is a native Python datatype which has an underlying C-double.  This is from the Python core rather than from *numpy* or *scipy*.

The [*numpy* and *scipy*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) types are more specific and tend to match your expectations:

```
bool_   Boolean (True or False) stored as a byte
int_    Default integer type (same as C long; normally either int64 or int32)
intc    Identical to C int (normally int32 or int64)
intp    Integer used for indexing (same as C ssize_t; normally either int32 or int64)
int8    Byte (-128 to 127)
int16   Integer (-32768 to 32767)
int32   Integer (-2147483648 to 2147483647)
int64   Integer (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)
uint8   Unsigned integer (0 to 255)
uint16  Unsigned integer (0 to 65535)
uint32  Unsigned integer (0 to 4294967295)
uint64  Unsigned integer (0 to 18446744073709551615)
float_  Shorthand for float64.
float16 Half precision float: sign bit, 5 bits exponent, 10 bits mantissa
float32 Single precision float: sign bit, 8 bits exponent, 23 bits mantissa
float64 Double precision float: sign bit, 11 bits exponent, 52 bits mantissa
complex_    Shorthand for complex128.
complex64   Complex number, represented by two 32-bit floats (real and imaginary components)
complex128  Complex number, represented by two 64-bit floats (real and imaginary components)
```

If your question is about why core Python uses the term `float` when the underlying C-type is `double`, the answer is that Python tries to be a higher level of abstraction than a low level language like C.  The term `float` represents the *concept* of a floating point number rather than a specific C type such as `float` or `double` which specify size.

In contrast, *numpy* allows lower level control of exact size and memory layout.  This is the key to its optimizations.  However those optimizations and ability to control details comes at a cost of moving the code away from the high level abstraction of "what you're trying to do" and into the world of "specifying the details of how it is done".